# Windows Embedded 8 Standard - "No images available" during install

Tags: windows-8, installation, embedded, product-key

I have previously been using a 180 day trial product key when installing WE8S, but recently acquired a licensed key. However, when using this key the installation fails.

I get a dialog asking me to select which operating system I want to install, followed by a list box where the only entry is "No images available".

When changing the product key back to the trial key, the installation works flawlessly.

Anybody know what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the fault was with the product key itself. They issued me a new product key, and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says, its will not be possible upgrade from win8 trial to sale version. And I think it won't be possible to install using sale key from trial dvd. If you buy product key without data carrier, you should get it from internet if it's possible (if licence grants and microsoft allows), or borrow (respect licences) or simple buy data carrier. otherwise its risk for licencing break. It depends on local law. In my district it is possible, I can make another data carrier copy for my own using. You must check how it's in yours.

Comment: I've purchased through a "Windows Embedded partner", and received official disks for 32/64 bit IBW and the Toolkit, and received a product key by filling out a form and sending to Microsoft. However, using this key the installer somehow fails to find a image to install

Comment: if you really use official production disk together with production licence key, only way I see is computer broken. Get from the Internet boot disk with memtest86 and put it to computer for 2 days. I was similar problem but with windows7 ultimate. Not allways installs. After install updates often failed.